Question about the spread of a disease. Similar to compound interest or continous compounding.
Suppose there are 5 people sick on the first week of an epidemic. During next week, they each make 4 people sick. How many people will be affected during tenth week of the epidemic?
Note: Many are saying the wording of this question is confusing. I tend to agree.
The reason I ask this question is because myself and some classmates of mine are debating 2 possible answers. One calculated as the sum of a geometric series with a rate of 4 and one calculated using the equation of continuous compounding. The former would be around 1.7 million with the ladder being 9.7 million. Any input would be appreciated. My way of looking at it is the following
Week 1: 5 people affected Week 2: Those 5 people from week 1 infect 4 so that's 20 plus the original 5= 25. Week 3: 125
That makes the rate 5 and using that and extrapolating to week 10 my preferred answer as of right now is around 9.7-9.8 million.

If there are $N$ infected people in a given week, the next week there will be $4N+N=5N$.  Thus, if we have $5$ infected in week $1$, there will be $5^n$ infected in week $n$.

Whether the rate is $5$ or $4$ might depend on (a) whether infected people stop bing infected (recovery or death) and (b) on whether you see doubling as a $100%$ increase in which case you call this doubling infection rate $2$ or $1$.  If infected people stay infected and keep on infecting $4$ other people in later weeks, then a result of $5^n$ looks reasonable and indeed $5^{10} = 9;765;625$

Has the wording been deliberately made confusing so as to leave room for different interpretations ? Just consider, it says "$5$ people sick on the first week,....  by the end of next week ... affected by the tenth week."
If I had to interpret it, i would take all figures to be at  the end of the corresponding week, so the compound weekly growth factor = $5$
and population affected at end of $10th$ week = $5\cdot 5^9 = 9\;765\;625$
which agrees with your interpretation

If we take the wording exactly as you’ve written it, then:

There were initially $5$ people sick.
By the end of the next week (after $2$ weeks), each of them had infected $4$ other people.

So by the end of two weeks, the number of infected people is $5+(5\times4)=25$.
By the end of four weeks, the number is $25+(25\times4)=125$.
By the end of six weeks, the number is $125+(125\times4)=625$.
Continuing with this pattern, the number of people infected by the tenth week is $15,625$.
